# Unable to reset mysql password for my Ubuntu machine

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Unable to reset mysql password for my Ubuntu machine. I followed the instruction below.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset

But I get the following error

```
sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking
151109 20:04:43 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.45) starting as process 18720 ...
151109 20:04:43 [ERROR] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!

151109 20:04:43 [ERROR] Aborting

151109 20:04:43 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

`sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking --user=mysql`

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html) might be of use. I copy-pasted the snippet for generic systems, as you didn't indicate whether you are using Unix or Windows:

1. Stop the MySQL server if necessary, then restart it with the --skip-grant-tables option. This enables anyone to connect without a password and with all privileges, and disables account-management statements such as ALTER USER and SET PASSWORD. Because this is insecure, you might want to use --skip-grant-tables in conjunction with --skip-networking to prevent remote clients from connecting.
2. Connect to the MySQL server using the mysql client; no password is necessary because the server was started with --skip-grant-tables: `mysql`
3. In the mysql client, tell the server to reload the grant tables so that account-management statements work: `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Now you can change the root password like any other user, e.g. using `set password` or `alter user`.

Hope that helps...